# SQL server JDBC driver close statement takes too long

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2012, mssql-jdbc

We are using SQL Server 2014. From the Java application using the Microsoft SQL server JDBC driver (latest one released in Jan'17) to connect to the SQL Server DB.

From the monitoring tool (App Dynamics), we find the statement close sometimes takes longer (up to around 7 secs as well). We cannot use jtds driver, as it does not support AGL.

Would request inputs from SQL experts who experienced similar issue  to help in resolving this issue

Comment: Very interesting but what's your question? and why aren't you telling Microsoft Support? instead of us?

Comment: Had raised ticket to Microsoft support as well. Wanted to know if anyone else experienced this issue and the workaround used by them

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Recently open sourced their driver. One can see [mssql-jdbc](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) driver activity on GitHub. I guess latest preview version is 6.1.6.

Also you can find all preview versions on maven too. This might help you.

> Meanwhile SQLServer 2014 is quite old. I am not even sure that
>   Microsoft is supporting 2014.

Thx. @Nivedita.

**UPDATE:** Microsoft is supporting SQL Server 2014 until 2019 and extended support until 2024 [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%202014%20Service%20Pack%202).

Comment: Microsoft is supporting SQL Server 2014 until 2019  and extended support until 2024. PFA support life cycle details https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%202014%20Service%20Pack%202

Comment: Are you using PreparedStatements ? I saw some perf improvement work in latest changelog. https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md